# How to pass list of conditions to method which checks all posibble combination of conditions?

Tags: python, list, function, dataframe

I have pandas data frame, and list of conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100, 'c3':120}, {'c1':11,'c2':110,'c3':120}, {'c1':12,'c2':120, 'c3':25}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
filter1 = df.c1>10
filter2 = df.c2>100
filter3 = df.c3>20
```

then i compare conditions where the rows hold true for all conditions at same time, and i take that rows

```
filter_df=np.diff(((filter1)&(filter2)&(filter3)))
df[np.insert(filter_df, 0, False)]
```

my code works, but how can I create a method where i can pass the list of conditions(maybe with for or while loop) and get back df? Something as following:

```
list_of_condition = [filter1, filter2, filter3]
def get_true(df, list_of_condition):
    filter_df=np.diff(((filter1)&(filter2)&(filter3)))
    df = df[np.insert(filter_df, 0, False)]
    return df
time = get_true(df, list_of_condition)
```

Here i separataly insert filters but i would like to pass just df and list of conditions. and check dataframe using list of condition with for loop maybe.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "How to pass list of conditions to method which checks all posibble combination of conditions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your function you can calculate the overall filter first

```
def get_true(df, list_of_condition):
    # calculate overall filter here
    all_filters = list_of_condition[0]
    for cond in list_of_condition[1:]:
      all_filters &= cond

    # do your thing
    filter_df=np.diff(all_filters)
    df = df[np.insert(filter_df, 0, False)]
    return df
```

Comment: Don't forget `any()` :)

Comment: thanks. Could you please explain, does this `all_filters &= cond` part do?

Comment: This is equivalent to `all_filters = all_filters & cond`.